# How to get attribute value of A-Tag with beautifulsoup - based on condition: title string contains keywords

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have html object that looks like this from the website [here](https://www.researchconnections.org/childcare/studies/36149/datasets/1/sdaxml/variable?var=V7551)

```
<li id="V7551"><a href="/childcare/studies/36149/datasets/1/sdaxml/variable?var=V7551" name="V7551" target="new" title='Item number: 31680  F1

Not counting work for school or a job, about how many hours a week do you spend on the Internet e-mailing, instant
messaging, gaming, shopping, searching, downloading music, etc.?

1="None" 2="Less than 1 hour" 3="1-2 hours" 4="3-5 hours" 5="6-9 hours" 6="10-19 hours" 7="20-29 hours" 
8="30-39 hours" 9="40 or more"'><span class="select-varname">V7551</span> 2014 C09 #HR/W INTERNET S F1</a></li>
<li id="V7553"><a href="/childcare/studies/36149/datasets/1/sdaxml/variable?var=V7553" name="V7553" target="new" title='Item number: 31990  F1
```

I would like to iterate through all variables (each in "ul" tag) and extract the variable name (in this example "V7551") if there are keywords in the variable description ("a href" title attribute) such as "music".

I am trying to automate a task I'm doing and unfortunately have no web scraping experience.
Anyone have any tips on how to proceed? Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Based on your information, understood that you want to get the "variable" of each `a` in the navigation, that´s `title` attribute contains one or more keywords - Providing some of your written code could help to find a better solution.

**Solution could be**

define your list of keywords:

```
matches = ["music", "video", "phone"]
```

loop over all `a` tags and check if there is a match in `title` of the `a`:

```
for link in soup.find_all("a"):
    if any(x in link.get('title') for x in matches if link.get('title')):
        print(link.get('name'))
```

**Output example**

```
V7310
V7539
V7588
V7551
V7553
V7590
V7562
V7563
```